# EclipseのCtrl+Shift+Pに対応するVisual Studioのショートカットキーは、何ですか

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Eclipseの`Ctrl + Shift + P`（対応する括弧にジャンプ）に対応するVisual Studioのショートカットキーは、何ですか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl + ]`です。

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.0.1のC#のエディター上で確認しました。

参考
以下のURLのEdit.GotoBraceの欄
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019